Extract specific row of a CSV file, indexed by timestamp using pandas
I have a csv file, which looks as following when printed

what confuses me is that there is 'time' instead of indexing. When I try accessing key file['time'] of course I get a mistake... What I'm trying to achieve is get the '00:01:00' time for each day in my csv file.. Sorry if it is not explained as well as it should.
Update:
After printing file.index, this is the output:
DatetimeIndex(['2024-05-08 00:01:00', '2024-05-08 00:02:00',
               '2024-05-08 00:03:00', '2024-05-08 00:04:00',
               '2024-05-08 00:05:00', '2024-05-08 00:06:00',
               '2024-05-08 00:07:00', '2024-05-08 00:08:00',
               '2024-05-08 00:09:00', '2024-05-08 00:10:00',
               ...
               '2024-05-08 21:44:00', '2024-05-08 21:45:00',
               '2024-05-08 21:46:00', '2024-05-08 21:47:00',
               '2024-05-08 21:48:00', '2024-05-08 21:49:00',
               '2024-05-08 21:50:00', '2024-05-08 21:51:00',
               '2024-05-08 21:52:00', '2024-05-08 21:53:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=1313, freq=None)


if it is already an index you can access it with file.index...

can you provide an example csv file along with the part of your code that results in an error?

@Zain unfortunately, this is as much as I can provide of the file.. Regarding the error, I just tried accessing the key 'time', because I saw it as a column when printed 'file.colums' as shown in the picture

@TinoD I updated the question, with the output of 'file.index', however I'm still not sure how to access the row, where time is 00:01:00 for each day

What I was trying to achieve is get the group of the time 00:01 for each day (datetime). I ran across this solution:
# Group by the date part of the index and select the first row of each group
first_rows_00_01 = test.groupby(test.index.date).first()

# Access the row corresponding to 00:01:00 for each day
row_00_01 = first_rows_00_01.loc[first_rows_00_01.index + pd.Timedelta(hours=0, minutes=1)]

which was exactly what I was looking for

great job, always nice to see people answering their questions! +1. There is some room for improvement, as this approach relies on 00:01:00 being the first date in the day, which could be not true in some cases

I guess using 'first_rows_00_01' directly works as well
